# scrapy xpath solution for xml with type=html and html entities

Tags: xpath, scrapy, lxml

I am scraping an atom feed (xml). One of the tags says:

```
<content type="html">
&lt;p&gt Some text and stuff &lt;/p&gt
</content>
```

Also i see the same html entities for img and a tags.
Is there a generic xpath to find the img tag or the p tag like this:

```
//content/p  or //content/img/@src
```

But obviously this does not work with these html entities. Or maybe an other solution with scrapy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to extract `content` text elements, and for each, parse HTML content using `lxml.html`

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

xmlfeed = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlfeedstring)
for content in xmlfeed.xpath('//content[@type="html"]/text()'):

    htmlcontent = lxml.html.fragment_fromstring(content)
    paragraphs = htmlcontent.xpath('//p')
    image_urls = htmlcontent.xpath('//img/@src')
```

See [Parsing HTML fragments](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html-fragments)  from lxml documentation.

Comment: This looks promising. I get an error for the htmlcontent row: *exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer*. Is it because the htmlcontent begins with **\n\n\n**, or maybe htmlcontent is all unicode?

Comment: are you using the result of `xmlfeed.xpath('//content[@type="html"]/text()')` directly or are you looping on each text element? could you share your whole code and sample XML feed perhaps?

Comment: Figured it out. The <content> tag had more html tags in it (mix of a, p and img). Then fragment_fromstring does not work, because it expects only one tag. Tried fragments_fromstring, but then you get a list :(

Comment: By the way i used method "fromstring" instead of "fragment_fromstring" because it was just easier to handle. Thnx for the great tip paul t!